# Navigate from one sso saml protected SP org to another saml protected SP org without logging into the 2nd SP?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I have 2 service providers, SP1 and SP2 both connected to an IDP through SSO and I have obtained my SAML response from IDP into SP1. 
Now, I want the user from SP1 to go to SP2 upon clicking a link/button without login credentials. The SP2
org should validate this user's authentication against the IDP.

Any thoughts on this would be really helpful.

Comment: This really depends on the IdP configuration. Some of them will keep the session available for a bit, others not so much. You'll need to refer to your IDP documentation.

Comment: Yes, the session is still alive but when I click the link from SP1, its taking me to SP2's login page which has the LOGIN WITH IDP button and upon clicking that button user lands to the SP2's home page. I don't want this intermediate step like showing the login page + IDP button to user, instead the user should directly see the SP2's home page.

Comment: Your IdP will assert requests from different SPs. And I don't think you can achieve the way you are trying to do. If you want to login from SP1 to SP2 without the need of reauthenticating, you will then need to set SP1 as IdP for SP2 and that it will be sort of an IdP initiated SSO. [This doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_examples_sf2sf.htm) should help you get more information.

Comment: But can a salesforce instance be both IDP as well as SP?